# Which regex to use to retrieve only text without repeated characters?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a following string:

```
<pre>one</pre><p><b>two</b></p>\n<pre>DO NOT    MATCH</pre><pre>BALLS</pre>
```

I want to match `<pre></pre>` tags and replace them with `<p></p>`

I do not want to match a part with multiple spaces

```
<pre>DO NOT!    !MATCH</pre>
```

Here it is my regex:

```
<pre>((?:[^\n]+?))</pre>
```

It matches all tokens inside `<pre></pre>` tags that are on a single line.

Actual result:

```
<p>one</p>
<p><b>two</b></p>\n<p>DO    NOT    MATCH</p>
<p>BALLS</p>
```

Expected result:

```
<p>one</p>
<p><b>two</b></p>\n
<p>BALLS</p>
```

[C# flavor demo](https://regex101.com/r/29ZLOo/1).

Comment: For small things it can be acceptable, but if you're looking for a generic tool for any HTML, I would avoid regex aside from simple selections. You're mathematically disadvantaged by only using regex here. Instead, you might consider an HTML/DOM parser (and swapping those tags yourself).

Comment: Regular expressions are the wrong tool for this job. Use an HTML parser. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c

Comment: FYI `[^\n]+?` is the same as `.+?`. Unless you enable the `DOTALL` flag, `.` doesn't match newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: consider this as an exercise. If you're planning to do something like this in real world development - please don't. Use HTML parser instead.

Since you basically need two different changes: convert good `<pre>` to `<p>` and remove bad `<pre>` let's do in in two steps:

```cs
string input = "<pre>one</pre><p><b>two</b></p>\n<pre>DO    NOT    MATCH</pre><pre>BALLS</pre>";

Regex regex_replace = new Regex(@"<pre>((?:(?<!\s{3})(?!</?pre>)[^\n])+?)</pre>");
Regex regex_delete = new Regex(@"<pre>[^\n]*?</pre>");

string result = regex_delete.Replace(regex_replace.Replace(input, "<p>$1</p>\n"), "");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output:

```
<p>one</p>
<p><b>two</b></p>
<p>BALLS</p>
```

Here `regex_replace` is used to replace good `<pre>` with `<p>`. It matches `<pre>` that don't contain other `pre` or three subsequent whitespace symbols.

And `regex_delete` removes all other pre's.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in full control of the HTML input, you can use this regex:

```
<pre>((?:[^<\s]\s?)*)</pre>
```

`(?:[^<\s]\s?)*` stands for "a sequence of non-blank characters excepted `<`, followed by at most one blank space, the whole thing repeated 0 or several times".

This sequence is then captured into the group `$1` ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Onujsx/1)).

---

As said by others, don't use regex to parse regular HTML content, or any stuff not belonging to regular languages.